# Getting length of text on SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, drawtext

I can draw text on SurfaceView by using drawText(). But sometimes part of text stay out of screen (horizontally) if text is long. For example:

```
canvas.drawText("this text is longer than screen ....", 10, 10, paint);
```

Is there any way to draw text in additional line?